# Draw vertical lines with datetime using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot `datetime` on x-axis and their values on the y-axis, and then draw vertical lines with different colors based on groups in a different column.

I am getting two errors.

1. `'0' key error`  - because of zeroes in `C` column
2. `AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'vline'`

input

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: '2020-01-01 06:00:00', 
                    1: '2020-01-01 18:00:00', 
                    2: '2020-01-02 06:00:00',
                    3: '2020-01-02 18:00:00',
                    4: '2020-01-03 06:00:00',
                    5: '2020-01-03 18:00:00',
                    6: '2020-01-04 06:00:00',
                    7: '2020-01-04 18:00:00'},
              'B': {0: 5, 1: 5, 2: 6, 3:6, 4:7, 5:7, 6:1, 7:1},
              'C': {0:'group1', 1:'group1', 2:'group2', 3:'group2', 4:'group3', 5:'group3', 6:'0', 7:'0'} })
```

code

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
colors = {0:'w','group1': 'r', 'group2': 'yellow', 'group3': 'grey'}
ax.vline(df['A'],df['B'], color=[colors[i] for i in df['C']])
ax.bar(df['A'], df['B'], linestyle='-',color='midnightblue' ,lw=6, width=0.01)
```

Comment: ｀ax.vlines()` is collect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fixes are `color.get()` and `ax.vlines` for accessing the dictionary and drawing vertical lines.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
colors = {'0':'w','group1': 'r', 'group2': 'yellow', 'group3': 'grey'}

for i in range(len(df)):
    v = colors.get(df['C'][i])
    ax.vlines(df['A'][i], 0, df['B'].max(), color=v)

ax.bar(df['A'], df['B'], linestyle='-', color='midnightblue', lw=6, width=0.01)
```

[image]

Comment: How can change this to draw full vertical lines (of groups) instead of value range?

Comment: `ax.vlines(df['A'][i], ymax=df['B'].max(), ymin=df['B'].min())` You can specify it like this.

Comment: what is `x` here?

Comment: That's because the minimum value is 1. So change it to `ymin=0`.

Comment: yes. just did thanks. I get a different error `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'`.

Comment: I get this error with that `TypeError: vlines() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ymax'`

Comment: Did you run it with the new code? The `ax.vlines(x, ymin,ymax)`three data are required, and the third one, `ymax', is missing.